# Expand Authority To Standing Basis

Tags: ellipsis

In [some news article](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/01/15/world/americas/15havana.html?_r=0):

> But the Guantánamo base commander asked the local commander in Cuba to ***expand the authority to a standing basis***, and Havana agreed, administration officials said.

Is something missing in "expand the authority to a standing basis"? Would "expand the authority ***to be on a standing basis***" or "expand ***the operational basis of*** the authority to a standing basis" be better?

Comment: Your "to be on a standing basis" does help clarify the meaning I think, but the statement as is, is not incorrect- just terse.

Answer (score 2):

One cannot quote an entire article of four sentences without running foul of fair usage laws, but I'll throw in the sentence that proceeds that of the question:

> An arrangement already exists between the United States and Cuba permitting violations of airspace for emergency medical flights.

followed by the sentence in the OP:

> But the Guantánamo base commander asked the local commander in Cuba to expand the authority to a standing basis, and Havana agreed, administration officials said.

So the existing arrangement is for emergencies. Or on an emergency basis. The proposed expansion is to a standing basis. No, I don't see anything missing. *On a standing basis* is a prepositional phrase, but then so is *to a standing basis.* One phrase might be more familiar, but both are complete.

Comment: Would replacing authority with arrangement, like "But the Guantánamo base commander asked the local commander in Cuba to expand the arrangement to a standing basis..." be better?

Comment: @meatie Define "better." In the meantime, I'll say that if the indirect quote uses the word (authority) that was actually said, then I might say its better to keep the original word. Your question implies you are uncomfortable with the word _authority_, yet it can mean _authorization_. Do you like that "better"?

Comment: How about  "expand ***the use of*** the authority to a standing basis"?  When people "expand [something] to a [X] basis", that "[something]" is usually an activity/process, and that "[X] basis" describes the pattern of the activity/process (like how often it happens, etc).

Comment: @meatie You seem to have resolved to dislike the original statement and are determined to improve it to your liking. I prefer to understand what was said, and leave it at that.

Comment: So, the original was most perfectly well-written?

Comment: @meatie It was written as indirect speech. How can one improve on what someone apparently said? Also, government employees, including the military, often use words in  a different way than the general public. There are basically several dialects of government-speech and military-speech, employing all kinds of acronymns and also words (such as authority, perhaps) in a different manner than the non-government citizens.